# How to process a string in a cell with MatLab

Tags: matlab

```
'10004_1'     '01:27:29'                '27'         'Uncertainty'                   ''
'10004_2'     '02:03:10'                '3:29'       'Neutral'                       ''
'10004_3'     '01:01:01'                '5:31'       'Neutral'                       ''
'10004_4'     '01:10:02'                '1:16'       'Neutral'                       ''
```

I have above sample data and these "%%:%%:%%" format data needed to be processed in the following way.

```
i.e. 01:27:29 => (((1*60+27)*60)+29)*30 which would be a numeric value.
```

I tried using cellfun, and the function used in cellfun would split the string with ':', and make the calculation. Maybe some other ways. Newbie to Matlab, really no clue. In the meantime, I will try the function to see if would work. Please feel free to let me know your thoughts or sample codes. Appreciate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = '01:23:12';
nums = textscan(text, '%d:%d:%d');
rst  = (((nums{1} * 60 + nums{2}) * 60) + nums{3}) * 30;
```

Comment: Thanks, prgao. This is exactly the answer I want.